# Angular select with ng-repeat loses selected option when options are updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an editor for a dynamic list using AngularJS. For each item I would like to add a select list containing options for all elements in the list. When an item is added to the list (Add button in the JSFiddle), the other selects lose their values. The model is not affected by this, only the view. What am I missing?

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bemy5wj/).

View:

```
<div ng-controller="selectDemoCtrl">{{msg}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>references</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>
                <input ng-model="item.id" type="number">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select ng-model="item.ref">
                    <option ng-repeat="i in items" value="i.id" ng-selected="item.ref==i.id">{{i.id}}</option>
                </select>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
    <div>{{items | json}}</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
selectDemo.controller('selectDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        id: 1,
        ref: 2
    }, {
        id: 2,
        ref: 1
    }];

    $scope.addItem = function(){
        var newitem = {id: 1, ref:1};
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
            if ($scope.items[i].id >= newitem.id) { newitem.id = $scope.items[i].id + 1; }
        }
        if ($scope.items.length > 0){newitem.ref = $scope.items[0].id;}
        $scope.items.push(newitem);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use ngRepeat, it's not reliable for binding model. Use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead, it should work as expected:

```
<select ng-options="i.id as i.id for i in items" ng-model="item.ref"></select>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/4bemy5wj/1/